# Как работает сборщик проектов?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Не смог найти информации по тому как работает сборщик проектов, таких как Gradle. Насколько я понимаю, он устанавливает классы, которые включены пользователем, как зависимость, а свою локальную директорию и управляет classpath'ом программы, прав ли я? Не могли бы посоветовать статьи на данную тему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle это так сказать вершина (на текущий момент) сборщиков проектов. Для того, чтобы понимать как он работает надо посмотреть на историю вопроса

На заре развития прогеры запускали компиляторы врукопашную, далее это решили поручить разнообразным shell скриптам

1)На следующем этапе появился `make` - юниксовый инструмент сборки проектов. Выглядит он крайне примитивно, но зато обладает всеми необходимыми и существующими по сей день понятиями `target/depend`, которыми оперирует любой сборщик проектов:

```
target1: depend1, depend2,... //означает target1 зависит от depend1, depend2
    recipe1                   //рецепт получения target1, например вызов компилятора

target2: target1              //для получения target2 нужно получить target1
    recipe2
```

По сути `make` файл - это набор target/depend, который анализируется программой и в итоге строится некий граф зависимости и чтобы получить глобальный target запускается цепочка `recipe`

Обратите внимание, что здесь вообще речь не идет о компиляторах, о сборщиках и уж тем более о Java/C++ - `make` - универсальный инструмент управления зависимостями.

Инструментов подобных `make` много `nmake/cmake/ant` и т.д.

2)Следующий прорывной момент произошел с появлением `maven`, который в отличие от `make` подобных инструментов позволил автоматически скачивать некоторые зависимости из сетевых репозиториев, в остальном `maven` не отличается принципиально от `make` (в последних версиях `maven` также есть плагины, которые действуют схожим с `Gradle` способом - см. ниже)

3)`Gradle` в отличие от `maven` позволяет автоматизировать само построение графа зависимостей, нет необходимости определять зависимости врукопашную (как в `make/maven`). Gradle имеет тучу разнообразных плагинов, которые сами позволяют определять зависимости. Скажем плагин для Android понимает  как выглядит стандартная программа для Android что в ней есть исходные java тексты, есть ресурсы, есть манифесты и проч., которые он автоматически включает в зависимости. Плагин также понимает этапы построения проекта на Android: генерацию `R.java`, компиляцию ресурсов с помощью `apt`, Java компиляцию, перевод JVM байткода на `DEX` и т.д. и соответственно генерирует подзадачи.

4)Появляются и другие инструментарии, которые позволяют автоматизировать этап развертывания (*deployment*) и документирования приложения и часть задач *devops* - в частности народ в последнее время пищит от Jenkins

Answer (score 4):

Такие инструменты управляют сборкой проектов разбивая сборку на фазы и управляя каждой фазой по отдельности.

Фазами могут быть, например: очистка временных директорий, компиляция классов, запуск тестов, упаковка скомпилированного кода в неких архив.

Для компиляции, например, могут понадобиться сторонние библиотеки, поэтому такие инструменты выкачивают нужные версии  "зависимостей" в локальные репозитории и при компиляции передают компилятору эти зависимости как `classpath`.

Кроме того, при упаковке скомпилированного в архив, инструмент смотрит на скоуп зависимости и может принять решение о том включать ли зависимость в сам архив или нет.

Обычно существуют некие дефолтные "настройки", минимизирующие усилия по формированию билд файлов, но всегда существует возможность все переопределить для поддержки кастомных процессов сборки.